# How to expand row in a table using typescript or javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7, angular15

I have used angular 7.I am trying to expand and collapse table row by clicking name and place. But it is not opening properly.
If i click place name, that place details only i want to show. But in my code it is opening all place details, Same for Name. How to resolve this issue.

app.component.html:

```
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <th> Name </th>
        <th> Place </th>
        <th> Phone </th>
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
<ng-container *ngFor="let data of data1">
  <tr>
    <td (click)="expanded1 = !expanded1"> <a href="javascript:void(0)">{{data.name}}</a> </td>
    <td (click)="expanded2 = !expanded2"> <a href="javascript:void(0)">{{data.place}} </a></td>
    <td> {{data.phone}} </td>
  </tr>

  <ng-container *ngIf="expanded1">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
      <div>Name Details:{{data.name}}</div>  
      </td> 
    </tr>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container *ngIf="expanded2">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
      <div>Place Details:{{data.place}}</div>  
      </td> 
    </tr>
  </ng-container>


</ng-container>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
      expandContent = true;
      expanded1 = false;
      expanded2 = false;
      data1 = [{
        'name': 'john',
        'place': 'forest',
        'phone': '124-896-8963',
        'expanded': false
      }, {
        'name': 'Jay',
        'place': 'City',
        'phone': '124-896-1234',
        'expanded': false
      }, {
        'name': 'Joseph',
        'place': 'sky',
        'phone': '124-896-9632',
        'expanded': false
      },
      ]
       
    }
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3hylrt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 2):

You have a few problems.  You are setting `(click)="expanded1 = !expanded1"` but then you are checking for `*ngIf="expanded"`. This is a typo, but since you want to toggle each one individually you need to be setting `data.expanded = !data.expanded` instead of the shared boolean.

You are also setting the `(click)` on the `<td>` element for some reason, and then you make the link itself useless by adding `href="javascript:void(0)"` which will probably cancel the click event.  Instead, put the click on the link since that's standard practice, and just change the CSS to make the link without an `href` appear clickable. You are using bootstrap, so just use the utility classes from that.

Also, not a "problem" but there's no need to wrap certain elements with a `<ng-container>` when you can just put the `*ngIf=""` directly on the `<tr>` element.

So here are the changes I am proposing

```css
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

tr a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```
export class AppComponent {
  data1 = [
    {
      name: 'john',
      place: 'forest',
      phone: '124-896-8963',
      expanded1: false,
      expanded2: false,
    },
    {
      name: 'Jay',
      place: 'City',
      phone: '124-896-1234',
      expanded1: false,
      expanded2: false,
    },
    {
      name: 'Joseph',
      place: 'sky',
      phone: '124-896-9632',
      expanded1: false,
      expanded2: false,
    },
  ];
}
```

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let data of data1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a
        class="d-block link-primary"
        (click)="data.expanded1 = !data.expanded1">
        {{ data.name }}
      </a>
      {{data.expanded1}}
    </td>
    <td>
      <a
        class="d-block link-primary"
        (click)="data.expanded2 = !data.expanded2"
      >
        {{ data.place }}
      </a>
      {{data.expanded2}}
    </td>
    <td>{{ data.phone }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngIf="data.expanded1">
    <td colspan="3" class="bg-light">
      <div>Name Details:{{ data.name }}</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngIf="data.expanded2">
    <td colspan="3" class="bg-light">
      <div>Place Details:{{ data.place }}</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

[StackBlitz Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anfvpx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

---

Here is an example of how to modify an object by adding properties to each item in the array

```js
const dataFromServer = [
  {
    name: 'john',
    place: 'forest',
    phone: '124-896-8963',
  },
  {
    name: 'Jay',
    place: 'City',
    phone: '124-896-1234',
  },
  {
    name: 'Joseph',
    place: 'sky',
    phone: '124-896-9632',
  },
];

const modifiedData = dataFromServer.map(d => {
  d.expanded1 = false;
  d.expanded2 = false;
  return d;
});

console.log(modifiedData);
```

Comment: It is opening all. Why?

Comment: Sorry, fix that

Comment: I am trying without adding expanded1 and expaneded2 property in the array object

Comment: Can you check this code correct or not? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdnf4c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: So, yes in general you are doing it right but you need to have the initial property values on each item in your `data1` array so they can be unique to each item. Check my updated answer

Comment: I am getting the json data from server. I am not able to add these two property(expanded1 and expanded2). In this case how to resolve it?

Comment: You have any solution?

Comment: You can add those properties to the data after you get it from the server. That would be the easiest way. Again, i have update my answer at the bottom to show you how to do this.

Comment: I have tried. I think that is not possible. Bcoz if i add these need to update interface also. that is not possible. Better without adding these two properties in the json data. So,Please give solution for that.

Comment: Your question target has shifted 3 times now. First it was about expanding table rows in Angular, then it was about modifying incoming JSON data, and now it is about typescript interfaces. This is going way off topic for what you have originally asked. Please make a new question for this. I am not going to keep amending my solution to account for everything you forgot to include in your original question.

Comment: I am not getting solution for my question. Please check my question. I did not added those two properties inside Json data. Actually, i am trying to find solution without adding those properties inside Json data. So, please answer how to achieve without adding that two properties inside json data.

Comment: Please ask a new question that properly explains everything. If typescript interfaces are related, please include those.  This question and the discussion around trying to figure out what you need here it getting too long and complicated. Please ask a new focused question for what you now know you need.